# AwsBackUp supports cross region copy in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-backup

Does `terraform` support `aws` backup feature for cross region copy (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/backup_plan.html )?

As I read the document I can see that it does support.

But I get the following error:

> Error: Unsupported argument
>     on backup_plan.tf line 11, in resource "aws_backup_plan" "example":
>     11:         copy_action = {
>   An argument named "copy_action" is not expected here.

My `terraform` file for your reference

```
resource "aws_backup_plan" "example" {
    name = "example-plan"
    rule {
        rule_name = "MainRule"
        target_vault_name = "primary"
        schedule = "cron(5 8 * * ? *)"
        start_window = 480
        completion_window = 10080
        lifecycle {
            delete_after = 30
        }
        copy_action {
            destination_vault_arn = "arn:aws:backup:us-west-2:123456789:backup-vault:secondary"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I remove the block

```
copy_action {
            destination_vault_arn = "arn:aws:backup:us-west-2:123456789:backup-vault:secondary"
        }
```

It works just fine

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running a version of the Terraform AWS Provider of 2.57.0 or older.

[Version 2.58.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2580-april-16-2020) (released 3 days ago) brought support for the `copy_action`:

> `resource/aws_backup_plan`: Add rule configuration block `copy_action` configuration block (support cross region copy)

You can specify in your code to require at least this version as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.58.0"
}
```